# Custom Jetbrains Plugin - Missing Dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-platform-psi

I'm trying to build my own custom line marker for Clion following this tutorial - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/line-marker-provider.html . My question is about the language attribute on the extension tag in the `plugin.xml` file ...

```xml
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
  <codeInsight.lineMarkerProvider language="JAVA"
          implementationClass="org.intellij.sdk.language.SimpleLineMarkerProvider"/>
</extensions>
```

When i add this extension the `language="JAVA"` gets highlighted in red. What plugin/dependency do i need to add for this to be resolved?

My IDE is also not able to resolve `PsiIdentifier` and `PsiMethod` from the provided snippet ...

```java
public class MyCorrectLineMarkerProvider implements LineMarkerProvider {
  public LineMarkerInfo getLineMarkerInfo(@NotNull PsiElement element) {
    if (element instanceof PsiIdentifier && element.getParent() instanceof PsiMethod) return new LineMarkerInfo(element, ...);
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is what my build.gradle looks like, i know there are some other dependencies i need to add but the tutorial i've been following isn't very clear about it.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.2.0'
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version = '2021.2.2'
}

runIde {
    jvmArgs '--add-exports', 'java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED'
}

patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes = """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: You can  use the community Open API forum for a question, related to plugin development: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979 .

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dependency on the `java` plugin in your `build.gradle`, like so

```
intellij {
    plugins = ['java']
}
```

See the [IntelliJ Dev Guide](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-dependencies.html#2-project-setup) for more information on plugin dependencies.

The tutorial you are following is meant for adding support for a new language, instead you are adding a line marker to Java (existing language :p). Plugin dependencies are simply outside the scope of that tutorial.